# Toggle anchor to work only in the first child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, anchor

I have been trying to make -just- the first child of: ".accordion-media-types a" to work.
At the moment, every anchor is toggling and grabbing the style of ".accordion-media-types" while they should be a regular looking link, so I just need the first one to work, is it possible somehow?

http://jsfiddle.net/0mpuh2f2/8/

html:

```
 <ul class="accordion-media-types">
    <li>    
        <a href="">Info</a>
        <div class="hidden-content">
           <ul>
              <li>
                 <a href="">link</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-media-types a', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('.accordion-media-types').toggleClass('active').find('.hidden-   content').slideToggle(500);
});
```

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use direct child selector: `.accordion-media-types > li > a`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-media-types > li > a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active').find('.hidden-content').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Read about child selectors [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

Also note that you probably want to toggle only closest `li` hidden content, not all of them at once.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0mpuh2f2/11/